# relationship between webview and the libc.so file In Android

Tags: android, c, http, webview

i used the code `Webview.loadurl("www.google.com")`

and I know that
using the dynamic analysis tool, in the `libc.so` module, the `connection()` function is used.

*connection format is connection(sockfd, addr, addrlen)
parameter:addr include "www.google.com" URL

I would like to know how this module and WebKit work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc6YH.png)

Comment: Do not include images: copy the text, so that it is more search engine friendly, and also for us to paste and copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libc is the standard system library, including standard C library, POSIX, and other Linux and possibly android extensions).

So nearly all libraries need libc to work: they use it to call the system. Very seldom libraries call directly the kernel (because libc provide most of the call, but few special use calls).

Libc is very complex. You may read C books and POSIX. For implementation, you can Google: you will find a lot. Some complete, some made for tiny systems. Often they are open source, so you can check the implementation. Possibly try the small libraries (for embedded systems): the code is much more readable. Avoid glibc (now near the reference): it should be compiled for too many systems, so the code is made compatible with old and broken compilers, at cost of readability (but use glibc documentation).

Comment: Thank you. It has helped a lot.